# Converting unicode stored as variable to plain text (eg: "\u0044" to "D")

Tags: python, string, unicode, utf-8, type-conversion

I am parsing/extracting unicode from a .htm file, and storing them as variables. Problem is, i want it printed as its plain text/letters. This is my code:

```
with open("Peribahasa.htm", "r") as Peribahasa_File:
for line in itertools.islice(Peribahasa_File, 1000, 1150):
    for item in line.split("\n"):
        if "I[0][1][0][0]" in item:
            answer_1 = (((item.strip()).replace("I[0][1][0][0] = '", "")).replace("';", ""))
            print(answer_1.encode('utf-8'))
```

However, the final  print line prints it as -> b'\u0044'
For reference the answer_1 variable is -> \u0044

I just need to convert the \u0044 to the letter D

Any help at all is appreciated! Ive been at this for hours, thank you!

Im using Python 3

Comment: I think you need decode().

Comment: @quamrana I just tried that,

answer_1 = (((item.strip()).replace("I[0][1][0][0] = '", "")).replace("';", ""))
                answer_1.decode()
                print(answer_1)

still prints out \u0044

Comment: No need to decode, the string '\u0044' is the letter 'D'. However, the type of your variable is a buffer (`b'\u0044'`) and not a string (`'\u0044'`), and I can't tell here how you converted it to a buffer because the code is too long and requires external input

Comment: @NadavS What other information might you need to help me identify what made it a buffer here?

In the .htm file, the original line was -> I[1][1][0][0] = '\u0049'; and i replaced everything but \u0049 with nothing, leaving only \u0049

Comment: Actually I might be able to guess - try replacing the last line with `print(answer_1)`, see if it outputs a `D`.

Comment: @NadavS nope, prints \u0044 i also checked the type of answer_1 and its a str

Comment: See, a line earlier you called `.replace()` on `answer_1` (with string arguments), which suggests it must be an `str`. Try rewriting your code using only 1 or 2 lines, shortening `Peribahasa.htm` to only one line, then attaching both to the question. That should make it easy to debug it for you, and you might even find the issue yourself.

Comment: `b'\u0044'` is not a valid literal. Perhaps it's really `b'\\u0044'`, ie. literally a backslash, the letter "u" and four digits? In that case, you'll need to decode with "unicode-escape". Or maybe it's embedded JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
answer_1.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: Works flawlessly! Thank you so much!